# How does the transpose of the derivative equal minus the derivative?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

The following is from Gilbert Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra.

> The inner product of functions
>   $$x^Ty=(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)y(t)\;dt$$
>
> From this inner product we know the requirement on $A^T$. The word "adjoint" is more correct than "transpose" when we are working with derivatives.
>
> The transpose of a matrix has $(A\mathbf x)^T\mathbf y=\mathbf x^T(A^T\mathbf y)$. The adjoint of $A=\frac d{dt}$ has
>
> $$(Ax,y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{dt}y(t)\;dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)\left(-\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\;dt=(x,A^Ty)$$
>
> **I hope you recognize integration by parts.** The derivative moves from the first function $x(t)$ to the second function $y(t)$. During that move, a minus sign appears. This tells us that **the transpose of the derivative is minus the derivative.**

If we perform integration by parts using $u=y(t)$ and $dv=\frac{dx}{dt}\;dt$, we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{dt}y(t)\;dt=x(t)y(t)\Big|_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)\frac{dy}{dt}\;dt$$

How does $x(t)y(t)\Big|_{-\infty}^\infty$ become zero? For sigmoid functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, this can be equal to $1$.

Comment: What are the hypothesis on $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: @nicomezi According to the text, $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$. No additional assumptions are stated.

Comment: No condition that $x^Tx$ is finite?

Comment: @random No, it is not stated in the text. If $x^Tx$ is finite, does that make $x(t)y(t)\Big|_{-\infty}^\infty=0$?

Comment: Then I guess this paragraph is just a non formal argument to emphasize the fact that we can give a more general meaning to the transposition operation. But indeed there is a lot of spaces where this computation makes no sense.